# Can we use the detection idiom to check if a class has a member function with a specific signature?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

Given a (reduced) implementation of the [detection idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf)

```
namespace type_traits
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    using void_t = void;

    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename, template<typename...> class, typename...>
        struct is_detected : std::false_type {};

        template<template<class...> class Operation, typename... Arguments>
        struct is_detected<void_t<Operation<Arguments...>>, Operation, Arguments...> : std::true_type {};
    }

    template<template<class...> class Operation, typename... Arguments>
    using is_detected = detail::is_detected<void_t<>, Operation, Arguments...>;

    template<template<class...> class Operation, typename... Arguments>
    constexpr bool is_detected_v = detail::is_detected<void_t<>, Operation, Arguments...>::value;
}
```

we can easily check if a class `foo` contains a member function `bar`

```
struct  foo {
    int const& bar(int&&) { return 0; }
};

template<class T>
using bar_t = decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(0));

int main()
{
    static_assert(type_traits::is_detected_v<bar_t, foo>, "not detected");
    return 0;
}
```

However, as you can see, we cannot detect that `foo::bar`'s argument type is `int&&`. The detection succeeds, cause `0` can be passed to `foo::bar`. I know that there are plenty of options to check for the *exact* signature of a (member) function. But I would like to know, if it's possible to modify this detection toolkit in order to detect that `foo::bar`'s argument type is exactly `int&&`.

[I've created a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/207d4486edb89ac3) of this example.]

Comment: It's simple if the only unknown part is the return type. Do you also want to cover multiple arguments where you only want to specify some precisely? What about cv- and ref-qualifiers of the member function?

Comment: Something like this? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38ffdc13080301c6

Comment: @dyp Currently, `is_detected_v<bar_t, T>` will detect if `T` has *any* member function `bar` which accepts an `int`. In a first step, I would like to add some kind of `is_detected_exact` which detects if `T` has a member function `bar` whose argument type is *exactly* `int` or *exactly* `int&&` or *exactly* `int const&`, etc. In a second step, I would like to verify an exact return type too, but I guess this is easy, cause `bar_t` is exactly the return type (whenever the expression inside `decltype(...)` is well-formed).

Comment: @dyp Yes, something like this! Can we replace the `bar_helper` by some utility of the `functional` header?

Comment: Well for my solution, you need type deduction of at least the return type. I do not know of any such tool in `<functional>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting the ideas of [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) and [Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35844717/547231), I've came up with

```
template<class T, typename... Arguments>
using bar_t = std::conditional_t<
    true,
    decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<Arguments>()...)),
    std::integral_constant<
        decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<Arguments>()...)) (T::*)(Arguments...),
        &T::bar
    >
>;
```

Notice that `bar_t` will be the return type of a `bar` call. In this way, we stay consistent with the toolkit. We can detect the existence by

```
static_assert(type_traits::is_detected_v<bar_t, foo, int&&>, "not detected");
```

However, while this solution does exactly what I intended, I hate that I need to write "so much complicated code" for every method I want to detect. I've asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847567/how-can-we-modify-the-detection-toolkit-to-check-if-a-class-has-a-member-functio) targeting this issue.

Comment: Can be simplified to `template<class T, typename... Arguments>
using bar_t = typename std::integral_constant<
        decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<Arguments>()...)) (T::*)(Arguments...),
        &T::bar
    >::value_type;`

Answer (score 7):

Without changing your type_traits, you may do

```
template<typename T, T> struct helper {};

template<class T>
using bar_t = decltype(helper<const int& (T::*)(int&&), &T::bar>{});
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2048463030d5241)

Comment: Where `helper` can be replaced with `integral_constant`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this works for checking const qualifiers.

```
decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<Arguments>()...)) (T::*)(Arguments...)
```

always produces a non-const function pointer type, whereas `&T::bar` will produce a const function pointer if `bar` is marked const.

This will then fail trying to convert the const pointer type to the non-const pointer type for storage in `integral_constant`.