# How can we modify the detection toolkit to check if a class has a member function with a specific signature?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, type-traits

Given a (reduced) implementation of the [detection idiom](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4502.pdf)

```
namespace type_traits
{
    template<typename... Ts>
    using void_t = void;

    namespace detail
    {
        template<typename, template<typename...> class, typename...>
        struct is_detected : std::false_type {};

        template<template<class...> class Operation, typename... Arguments>
        struct is_detected<void_t<Operation<Arguments...>>, Operation, Arguments...> : std::true_type {};
    }

    template<template<class...> class Operation, typename... Arguments>
    using is_detected = detail::is_detected<void_t<>, Operation, Arguments...>;

    template<template<class...> class Operation, typename... Arguments>
    constexpr bool is_detected_v = detail::is_detected<void_t<>, Operation, Arguments...>::value;
}
```

[we can check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843485/can-we-use-the-detection-idiom-to-check-if-a-class-has-a-member-function-with-a/35847570#35847570) if a class `foo` contains a member function `bar`

```
struct  foo {
    int const& bar(int&&) { return 0; }
};

template<class T, typename... Arguments>
using bar_t = std::conditional_t<
    true,
    decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<Arguments>()...)),
    std::integral_constant<
        decltype(std::declval<T>().bar(std::declval<Arguments>()...)) (T::*)(Arguments...),
        &T::bar
    >
>;

int main()
{
    static_assert(type_traits::is_detected_v<bar_t, foo, int&&>, "not detected");
    return 0;
}
```

However, as you can see, we need to write "complicated code" for every method we want to detect.

> Can we encapsulate the idea of `bar_t` into a more generic test? I would like to provide the operation `foo::bar` and the desired argument type and perform a test like `static_assert(type_traits::is_detected_v<bar_t, foo, int&&>, "not detected");`.

[I've created a [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0754dbbf166974d3) of this example.]

Comment: why are you using `conditional_t` ?

Comment: Are you asking if we can detect arbitrarily named functions? Like check for `bar` with signature `int(int&&)`, via `is_detected<foo, bar, int, int&&>` and `baz` with signature `void(void)` similarly like `is_detected<foo, baz, void, void>`? If so, then I don't think it can be done. You need to enable the compiler to distinguish between overloads on members, and you do that by static casting, or by calling the function (or asking the compiler to give you the type of its return).` So I think it's possible overall, just not in the way you want.

Comment: @AndyG No, I'm asking if we can encapsulate the "complicated logic" behind `bar_t` into some easier to use trait.

Comment: @0xbadf00d but it's you who complicated [dyp's solution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38ffdc13080301c6)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: but Dyp's solution has false positive: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1792e7eedddb13f3).